# Terraform Remote Provisioning using GCP Service Account connection not working

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Below is what i want to achieve with terraform, and i am new to terraform
i want to create a VM and then copy a file from gcp storage to vm, i have started with file provisioner so that first i copy local shell script(which has gsutil commands to copy file from storage to vm).
i have tried in different ways , like remote provisioning which is not working

i have created a service account which has required permissions to create vms, manage storage  also , i am using same service account while provisioning

```
# Provider Configuration
provider "google" {
    credentials = "${file("terraform-vm-sa.json")}"
    project = "gcp-exp-test-npe"
    region = "us-east4"
}

data "google_service_account" "vmaccount" {
    account_id = "terraform-vm-sa"
}

resource "google_service_account_key" "vmkey" {
  service_account_id = "${data.google_service_account.vmaccount.name}"
}

resource "local_file" "vmkeyfile" {
    content = "${google_service_account_key.vmkey.private_key}"
    filename = "./vmprivatekey"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "test-inst" {
    name = "testq"
    machine_type= "n1-standard-1"
    zone = "us-east4-c"
    service_account {
        email = "terraform-vm-sa@gcp-exp-test-npe.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
    }

    boot_disk {
      initialize_params {
        image = "centos-cloud/centos-7"
      }
    }

    network_interface {
          subnetwork="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/gcp-exp-test-network-npe/regions/us-east4/subnetworks/npe-test-subnet-1"
    }
    metadata = {
        sshKeys = "terraform-vm-sa:${google_service_account_key.vmkey.public_key}"
     }
    provisioner "file" {
        source = "./storage-provision.sh"
        destination = "/tmp/storage-provision.sh"
        connection {
            host = "${google_compute_instance.test-inst.network_interface.0.network_ip}"
            user = "terraform-vm-sa"
            private_key = "${file("./vmprivatekey")}"
        }
    }

}

output "internal_ip" {
    value = "${google_compute_instance.test-inst.network_interface.0.network_ip}"
}
```

terraform is throwing below error

```
google_compute_instance.test-inst: Creating...
google_compute_instance.test-inst: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_compute_instance.test-inst: Provisioning with 'file'...


Error: Failed to read ssh private key: no key found
```

but i am able to see a file with private key generated, not able to understand why it's happening

```
➜  cat vmprivatekey
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
```

While i google i found different approaches like create a user inside script and create public, private key and with that user creating connection but i can't use that approach because i need to ssh with a user who has gcp role to copy file from storage

Can any one please suggest who can i solve this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have the answer to your terraform issue. However, for executing script on VM, I use [startup script url metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript?hl=fr)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thanks for the reply , as i have mentioned in the question there are multiple ways to solve, if i don't have to copy  from storage then we can use your solution

Comment: Is your file going to change with time? If not why not create a packer image containing your file?

Comment: @prasad even if you have file to copy from storage. Add a gsutil command in your startup script and that's all!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere i have tried that as well, looks like it's failing because during startup script execution time it doesn't have gcp credentials associated with that and this is my assumption because i have tried 4 different commands out of 4, 3 are successful and the one with gsutil is not successful